# How can I know which input tag a particular file in request.FILES was uploaded from?

Tags: python, html, django, html-input

Problem Description:

I have a django view and template which displays several paragraphs of data, which are retrieved from a Model. Below each one, is a `<input type="file">` tag, for uploading images related to each row of data. When user uploads files, he may upload 1 to several files for one particular row of the model, or he may choose not to upload files for one or more models. I need to save these files with a foreign key to that particular row. I am not using django forms for this.

To explain once again, there are several  file tags in my html, each below a particular set of text from different rows of a model. At POST, all files become collected into a list within request.FILES, with no clue as to from which input tag each was uploaded. I need to differentiate between files uploaded from different file tags, as these need to be saved to the model, referencing different rows by foreign key. *How can I know which input tag a particular file in request.FILES was uploaded from?*

My model:

```
class Procedure(models.Model):
    procid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    timestr = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    template = models.ForeignKey(ProcedureTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(doctor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.template} for {self.customer} on {self.timestr}'

class SectionHeading(models.Model):
    procid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    fieldtype_choice = (
        ('heading1', 'Heading1'),
        ('heading2', 'Heading2'),
        )
    fieldtype = models.CharField(
        choices=fieldtype_choice, max_length=100, default='heading1')

    template = models.ForeignKey(ProcedureTemplate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} [{self.procid}]'

class SectionText(models.Model):
    procid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    widgettype_choice = (
        ('textarea', 'Textarea'),
        ('text', 'Short Text'),
        )
    widgettype = models.CharField(
        choices=widgettype_choice, max_length=100, default='text')

    heading = models.ForeignKey(SectionHeading, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} [{self.procid}]'



class SectionImage(models.Model):
    procid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    pic = StdImageField(upload_to="data/media/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True, variations={
        'large': (600, 400),
        'thumbnail': (150, 140, True),
        'medium': (300, 200),
    })
    procedure = models.ForeignKey(Procedure, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pic.url
```

My view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    print(request.POST, "\n\n")        
    headinglist = request.POST.getlist('qn[]')
    valuelist = request.POST.getlist('ans[]')
    for h, v in zip(headinglist, valuelist):
        print(h, v)
    print(request.FILES)
    filelist = request.FILES.getlist('uploaded[]')
    for f in filelist:
        print(f)
        report_pic = SectionImage(pic = f, procedure=proc)
        report_pic.save()
        print(f'Saved picture to disk: {f}')
    msg = "Updated successfully"
```

My html:

```
{% for qn, ans in headingparagraph %}
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-24">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">{{ qn.name }}</label>
                <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="qn[]" value="{{ qn.procid }}">

            <textarea class="form-control reporttextarea" id=""  rows="3" name="ans[]">{{ ans }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
    <i class="fas fa-image fa-2x mx-2"></i> Upload Images <input type="file" class="mx-2" id="{{ qn.procid }}_upload" accept="image/*" name="uploaded[]" multiple />
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This gets displayed as:

```
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-24">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Nasal mucosa</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="qn[]" value="1">
            <textarea class="form-control reporttextarea" id="" rows="3" name="ans[]">Normal nasal mucosa</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
    <i class="fas fa-image fa-2x mx-2"></i> Upload Images <input type="file" class="mx-2" id="1_upload" accept="image/*" name="uploaded[]" multiple />
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-24">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Turbinates</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="qn[]" value="2">
            <textarea class="form-control reporttextarea" id="" rows="3" name="ans[]">Bilateral turbinates normal</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
    <i class="fas fa-image fa-2x mx-2"></i> Upload Images <input type="file" class="mx-2" id="2_upload" accept="image/*" name="uploaded[]" multiple />
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-24">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Middle meatus</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="qn[]" value="3">
            <textarea class="form-control reporttextarea" id="" rows="3" name="ans[]">Bilateral middle meatus normal</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
    <i class="fas fa-image fa-2x mx-2"></i> Upload Images <input type="file" class="mx-2" id="3_upload" accept="image/*" name="uploaded[]" multiple />
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-24">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Inferior Meatus</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="qn[]" value="4">
            <textarea class="form-control reporttextarea" id="" rows="3" name="ans[]">Inferior Meatus normal</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mb-2">
    <i class="fas fa-image fa-2x mx-2"></i> Upload Images <input type="file" class="mx-2" id="4_upload" accept="image/*" name="uploaded[]" multiple />
</div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I upload files for Turbinates and Inferior Meatus, but not for others, output on command line is:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['0dEBGstsSSzhOgebI2FBaHWioH7bEBmx0EPnYDE4nTrrNHZYMZCSTyId0FXAJYYR'], 'qn[]': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'ans[]': ['Normal nasal mucosa', 'Bilateral turbinates normal', 'Bilateral middle meatus normal', 'Inferior Meatus normal'], 'uploaded[]': ['', '']}> 
1 Normal nasal mucosa
2 Bilateral turbinates normal
3 Bilateral middle meatus normal
4 Inferior Meatus normal
<MultiValueDict: {'uploaded[]': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot from 2019-01-27 11-32-34.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot from 2019-01-26 16-25-56.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot from 2019-01-26 16-25-18.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Screenshot from 2019-01-27 11-32-34.png (image/png)>]}>
Screenshot from 2019-01-27 11-32-34.png
Saved picture to disk: Screenshot from 2019-01-27 11-32-34.png
Screenshot from 2019-01-26 16-25-56.png
Saved picture to disk: Screenshot from 2019-01-26 16-25-56.png
Screenshot from 2019-01-26 16-25-18.png
Saved picture to disk: Screenshot from 2019-01-26 16-25-18.png
Screenshot from 2019-01-27 11-32-34.png
Saved picture to disk: Screenshot from 2019-01-27 11-32-34.png
```

All the files get into a Querydict collection. I am unable to differentiate which section it belongs to. Is there any way I can tag specific  file tags so that when the form is submitted, I can iterate the list and save each file by tagging them to an individual section heading. The database part is easy. I want to know how to build the file tags/html.

Comment: Can you use unique names instead of `uploaded[]` for all?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't name fields with `[]`. That's a PHP/Rubyism, there's no need for it in Django.

But the way to have different names is to give the inputs those names. The name attribute of the input is what is used as the key in the FILES/POST dictionaries.